# Test missing character

Tags: fonts

Sometimes LaTeX will give the warning like

```
Missing character: There is no <xxx> in font <xxx>!
```

How to test it (I mean a macro like `\IfCharExist`)? And how to replace this missing character with something else like `\rule`?

Comment: Can you be more precise about your aim? Is this (Xe|Lua)LaTeX with some strange Unicode character?

Comment: Well, e-TeX has a `\iffontchar` primitive that tests whether a given slot number (0-255) corresponds to an existing character in a given font.  See pp. 13-14 of the e-TeX manual.

Comment: @GuM I found this question is dulplicated to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12567/136923).

Comment: Also possibly related: [How to detect an empty unicode slot in a font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202437/69818).